# How do i create a notification each time a new data is inputted with retrofit and REST API?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I've been making a simple app that has CRUD functionality using Retrofit and REST API (with PHP), i want to make a notification on my notification bar each time a data has been inputted, my question is how can i do that?

I'm new to android programming so i'd really appreciate if anyone could give a bit of example in here.
Also please feel free to ask any details about my app if needed. I hope my question is good enough for you to understand, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider implement a `firebase cloud messaging` in your `PHP` code for each time a data is inserted from the admin panal and then implement a `firebase cloud messaging service` in android using assistant in android studio

Comment: Don't forget to implement a `cloud messaging service` in android as well to handle those messages and show a notification from it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the php code to fire a notification. You will need a firebase key to get it working. You can get it in your firebase console.

```
<?php
    // Enabling error reporting
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');


    $title = isset($_GET['title']) ? $_GET['title'] : '';
    $body = isset($_GET['message']) ? $_GET['message'] : '';

    $message["title"] = $title;
    $message["body"] = $body;

     $fields = array(
                'to' => '/topics/global',
                'notification' => $message,
        );
    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result='';
    if($title!=null){   
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
}    
    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

Here is the official guide for firebase notification setup in android.
[Android FCM setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Comment: does it work with ordinary mysql? because i use ordinary mysql with phpmyadmin panel to work.

Comment: Yes even I use it with ordinary mysql. I use it with wamp server but tested this and worked successfully with xamp also. All you need to do is just put this file as a normal php and call it by url as you do with other php files with parameters.